# Hyperledger cost of peers for an organization

Tags: nodes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, peer

I'm researching the cost of an application that relies on the Hyperledger blockchain, but I don't understand if maintaining a node (peer) is expensive or not.
I find conflicting information, anyone can have an active node on their PC, but reading some documentation I find that having a peer is very expensive and there is support for services like [this](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B0797GK9YY).

So I would like to understand, for an organization how much it costs to have nodes on Hyperledger? Do they require specific hardware specifications?

Can anyone help me shed some light on the subject?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hardware:** Fabric docs didn't specifies minimum hardware requirements it will depend on the number and complexity of transactions, endorsement policies and your business, performance and security requirements.

**License:** Free

**Technical Support:** In my experience it's the most expensive side of use fabric. Fabric is a complex system, with complex configs and architecture. It demands skilled human resource in order to set up and maintain it working. The cost can vary by region and your requirements but its do uses to be cheap.

Comment: So can I create a node on every computer without any problems?
And connect them to my channel or other channels quietly?

Comment: Yes, but yo have to make sure your computers can see each others, in a enterprise level in most cases there are some firewalls rules and ports that need to be setup in other to make it work.
The fabric configuration is sometimes tricky, you need to generate certificates for each new pear and join them in the channel.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers, I don't know how the issue of certificates works, but now I inform myself.
Finally, excluding the necessary technical skills, a company can build its network of nodes, its channel and its applications (smart contract) on Hyperledger for free?